# How to mirror an array with WS2801 LEDs?

Tags: arrays, arduino, mirror

I have the following code http://pastebin.com/25ugwNhK# which basically reads the equalizer color values for 7 differenece frequencies and maps them to a color.  Then mirrors them projected on a string starting from both ends.

```
void EQcenterBarString(){
  // reads eq and plugs RGB values directly into each consecutive pixel, mirrored from     center.
  if(LoopCnt <= PixelCount) {
    readEQ();

//Add new color to array at pointer position
//For Array replace LoopCnt with row number
leds[LoopCnt].r = ledRed;
leds[LoopCnt].g = ledGreen;
leds[LoopCnt].b = ledBlue;

//now the opposite
//For Array replace Pixel - Loop with ROWS - row number
leds[PixelCount - LoopCnt].r = ledRed;
leds[PixelCount - LoopCnt].g = ledGreen;
leds[PixelCount - LoopCnt].b = ledBlue;

FastSPI_LED.show();  
LoopCnt++;    
  }else{LoopCnt=0;}
}
```

I'd like to make this be able to work with an Array of [ROWS] [COLS], however I'm struck with getting the pixels to update or loop through the array.

My pseudo code looks something like this:

```
void EQcenterBarArray(){

int pixel = 0, rows = 0, cols = 0;

//rows = 0, loop through till the end going down the array, rows++
for(rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)  {
readEQ();
      // should light up a whole row at once starting from the beginning of the array
while (cols != COLS) {  //while in row # x fill all the col values until = COL value
pixel = ( LEDmatrix[rows][cols] );  // set pixel index to the array pos
  leds[pixel].r = ledRed;
  leds[pixel].g = ledGreen;
  leds[pixel].b = ledBlue;
    FastSPI_LED.show(); //update the pixel and move to next col value
  cols++;  //should fill whole col on row x ?
}

//now the opposite side

    // should light up a whole row at once starting from the end of the array
while (cols != COLS) {
pixel = ( LEDmatrix[(ROWS-1) - rows][cols] );  //take the total# of ROWS and subtract the current row value to create a mirror effect?
  leds[pixel].r = ledRed;
  leds[pixel].g = ledGreen;
  leds[pixel].b = ledBlue;
    FastSPI_LED.show(); 
  cols++;
}
}
}
```

However, when I run this through my arduino with WS2801 lights using the FastSPI_LED library I only get one row to light up and it doesn't cycle through all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `cols` to 0 at the start of each iteration of your `rows` for() loop.

```
for(rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++)  {
   readEQ();
  // should light up a whole row at once starting from the beginning of the array
  cols = 0; //reset cols to zero to iterate next set of columns
  while (cols != COLS) {  //while in row # x fill all the col values until = COL value
```

Incidentally, it's not clear if you should call readEQ every row, or only after you have finished an entire display grid - each will have various advantages (rate of partial response, vs self-consistency of updates)